# Image filtering of QGraphicsView's background through foreground QGraphicsItems

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

The background of my QGraphicsView is set by overloading `.drawBackground(...)` and calling `painter.drawImage(...)`. I go on to add foreground objects to the associated QGraphicsScene. These are mostly of type QGraphicsRectItem. I'd like each of these foreground rectangles apply image filters to the subimage of the background that they cover.

- Is this possible?
- If so, where can I find a bit of example code to get me started? Googling tends to turn up nothing but code for event filtering.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your background is static, you could use this static image in the paintEvents of your (custom) item class. But as far as I know, you can't use Qt's item effects for this but need to implement the filters by your own in the paintEvents. Remember to crop the correct region out of the image for your filter.

There are some cases where you even don't need the background image. If you want to invert, for example, the background image covered by your item, just fill the whole region in the paintEvent of the item but set the composition mode of the painter *before* the drawing appropriately. (See [QPainter::CompositionMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) for the available modes.)

If the background isn't static, it won't be possible without reusing the code of the drawBackground method or drawing the background on an image and then use this image to draw the actual background + for the effects in each item.

For a more specific answer, you should provide more information about the background and filters you want to have for the items.